# Write byte array [][] to jpg

Tags: c#, bitmap

I have the following piece of code I wish to do without using the Bitmap Class
I am not sure where to start can someone give me some code samples or examples to work from

```
public class PgmImage
{
    public int Width { get; set; }
    public int Height { get; set; }
    public int MaxVal { get; set; }
    public byte[][] Pixels { get; private set; }

    public PgmImage(int width, int height, int maxVal,
        byte[][] pixels)
    {
        this.Width = width;
        this.Height = height;
        this.MaxVal = maxVal;
        this.Pixels = pixels;
    }
}
    private static Bitmap MakeBitmap(PgmImage pgmImage, int mag)
    {
        int width = pgmImage.Width * mag;
        int height = pgmImage.Height * mag;
        Bitmap result = new Bitmap(width, height);
        Graphics gr = Graphics.FromImage(result);
        for (int i = 0; i < pgmImage.Height; ++i)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < pgmImage.Width; ++j)
            {
                int pixelColor = pgmImage.Pixels[i][j];
                Color c = Color.FromArgb(pixelColor, pixelColor, pixelColor);
                SolidBrush sb = new SolidBrush(c);
                gr.FillRectangle(sb, j * mag, i * mag, mag, mag);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

The reason behind this is that NetStandard doesn't have the Bitmap class to use

Comment: Research a bit on what alternatives to `Bitmap` _are_ available on .NET Standard. Your own google on that subject is probably as good as mine.

Comment: For now you can use  [System.Drawing.Common](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Drawing.Common/4.5.0-preview1-25718-03) - [github](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/tree/master/src/System.Drawing.Common)